# Нормальная отправка почты с сайта.

Tags: php

Замучился с отправкой почты. Пробовал разные варианты скриптов. Самые простейшие еще срабатывают. Но и те, через раз.
Задача - отправить письмо с html на e-mail.
Например такой скрипт:

```
$addr = 'oleg-ismaylov@mail.ru';   
$mtext = 'Тут какой-то полезный текст.';   
$headers =  "Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251\r\n".   
               "From: site <admin@site.com>\r\n" .   
               "Reply-To: admin@site.com\r\n".   
               "MIME-Version: 1.0";   
$subject = "Тема";

mail($addr, $subject, $mtext, $headers);
```

Что-то там не срабатывает. Поможите кто-чем может.

Comment: Сделайте лучше отправку через SMTP

Comment: Или AmazonSES + DKIM — вообще вышка просто будет.

Comment: с `html` вы никак письмо не отправите.

Comment: @Maris, чтооо?

Comment: @oleg_ismailov, что значит

    Самые простейшие еще срабатывают. Но и те, через раз.

???

Когда не срабатывает - вообще ничего не доходит?

А если выбросить из заголовков Content-Type и MIME-Version?

Comment: Если выбросить, то доходит) Но тогда нельзя отправлять HTML, а очень хочется. Вероятно придется все ж на SMTP переходить.

Comment: Мне кажется, что почта (в смысле SMTP) в любом случае доходит, а вот клиент ее не всегда **отображает** (или какой-нибудь Анти-Спам выбрасывает).

Думаю, что если Вы пишете Content-Type: text/html, то и в $mtext должен быть **правильный** HTML.

Вообще можете попробовать еще с Content-Type: text/plain

Тогда по идее кодировку текста для клиента тоже можно указать.

Кстати, имейте в виду, что **доставка** почты между MTA и ее отображение для человека никак не связаны.

Comment: @avp, спасибо! Тоже попробую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У многих людей проблемы с реализацией отправки почты на PHP. Существует несколько решений.
Все проблемы из-за недоработанного HTTP 1.1, нужно знать какие заголовки выставлять. А для кириллицы ещё и проставлять мета-теги.

Мой скрипт реализован в виде двух файлов. Было обусловлено задачей.

email.php

```
<?php

    # Тут правим адрес получателя и тему сообщения

    define("TO_EMAIL", "test@test.ru");
    define("SUBJECT", "Тема сообщения.");

    function send($fromUserName, $fromUserEmail, $inputMessage)
    {
        $subject = "=?windows-1251?b?" . base64_encode(SUBJECT) . "?=";
        $from = "=?windows-1251?B?" . base64_encode($fromUserName) . "?= <" . $fromUserEmail . ">";

        $random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));

        $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\nReply-To: " . $from . "\"";
        $headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=\"windows-1251\"";

        ob_start();
        # Включили буфер, ниже строкой идёт захват сообщения в буфер, только текст! (Сделал для более удобного форматирования) 
        # Чтобы выводило html нужно в Content-type (выше строчка) заменить text/plain на text/html (не забываем про знак ';')
?>

<?php echo $inputMessage; ?>

<?php
        $message = ob_get_clean();
        # Забрали в перменную содержимое буфера, теперь всё готово для вывода!

        if(@mail(TO_EMAIL, $subject, $message, $headers))
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    # Фильтр для данных, обрезает пробелы по краям
    # Обрезает все html, php, js теги (на всяких случай)

    function _sanitize($field)
    {
        $field = trim($field);
        $field = strip_tags($field);
        return $field;
    }

?>
```

send.php

```
<?php

    require_once('email.php');

    /*
    ** Функция send высылает на e-mail письмо
    **
    ** @param senderName  - Имя пользователя
    ** @param senderEmail - E-mail пользователя
    ** @param senderMsg   - Сообщение пользователя, только текст!
    */

    $fromUser  = _sanitize($_POST['senderName']);
    $fromEmail = _sanitize($_POST['senderEmail']);
    $senderMsg = _sanitize($_POST['senderMsg']);

    if(send($fromUser, $fromEmail, $senderMsg))
        echo "Email send: Success!<br />";
    else
        echo "Email send: Error!<br />";

?>
```

Можете переделать send.php, тут, я думаю, всё ясно.

Ссылка на скрипт: [ссылка](http://dfiles.ru/files/tdtq5uman)

Comment: Я решил проблему отправки почты, а также прихода её в inbox (кроме gmail) — с помощью AmazonSES!

10к писем в сутки. 5 в секунду. Просто скидываю все что хочешь в api-метод, дальше amazon сам разберется.

Comment: Смотря для каких целей =)

Answer (score 1):

вот те мой класс

убери лишние переменные если остались (вроде удалил)

```
<?php
class email {

    private $mail_dump;
    private $def_data;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->mail_dump=array();
        $this->def_data=array('from'=>'','replyto'=>'','to'=>'','subject'=>'','message'=>'','charset'=>'windows-1251','html'=>false,'mime'=>false,'encode'=>false);
    }

    public function add_mail($email) {
        if(!empty($email)) {
            if(is_array($email)) {
                for($i=0;$i<count($email);$i++) {
                    if(!in_array($email[$i], $this->mail_dump)) {
                        array_push($this->mail_dump,$email[$i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                if(!in_array($email, $this->mail_dump)) {
                    array_push($this->mail_dump,$email);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function send(array $new_data) {
        $send_data=this->def_data;
        $this->add_mail($send_data['to']);
        for($i=0;$i<count($this->mail_dump);$i++) {
            $header='';
            if($send_data['mime']) {
                $header.="MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            }
            if($send_data['encode']) {
                $send_data['subject']='=?'.$send_data['charset'].'?B?'.base64_encode($send_data['subject']).'?=';
            }
            if($send_data['html']) {
                $header.="Content-type: text/html; charset=".$send_data['charset']."\r\n";
            }
            else {
                $header.="Content-type: text/plain; charset=".$send_data['charset']."\r\n";
            }
            if(!empty($send_data['from'])) {
                $header.="From: ".$send_data['from']."\r\n";
            }
            if(!empty($send_data['replyto'])) {
                $header.="Reply-To: ".$send_data['replyto']."\r\n";
            }

            if(mail($this->mail_dump[$i], $send_data['subject'], $send_data['message'], $header)) {
                //
            }
            else {
                //
            }
        }
    }

    public function clear() {
        $this->mail_dump=array();
    }

    public function show_mail() {
        return $this->mail_dump;
    }

    public function __destruct() {

    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть хороший класс для работой с почтой, сам его использую.
[phpmailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/)